# Split the string by regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I am in the process of writing string split functionality and realized that `split()` method can take regular expression. I should split it by whitespace.

I had found following regular expression construct can do that.

```
\p{Space}
```

How do I incorporate this in my String split() method.

Comment: Read documentation..`String []arr = str.split("\\p{Space}")`

Comment: [check](http://ideone.com/5N0T94)

Comment: While giving `\p` I had problem,- `Error`. So we need to precede with escape character. `str.split()` had taken up `"\\p{Space}"`. Thanks. Now I understood `regular expression constructs` can be used as is. Constructs which uses \ must be preceded with one more like \\.